# Forward X Display over multiple hops

Tags: docker, ssh, forwarding

**Background:**
I have the following topology:
A(Linux Laptop) <--> B(Linux Desktop) <--> C(Linux docker container on B)

From A I have setup:
`ssh -NL 2022:C:22 B&`

...and then from A I can ssh into C via:
`ssh -X -p 2022 user@localhost`

...This all works perfectly fine and I can log into to C from A - so far so good.

Caveat: C is actually a docker running on B.

**Problem:**
When ssh'ing into C from A using the ssh tunnel and running `xeyes` the XDisplay appears on B and not A.
The docker **is** exporting the display via the `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY` option.

What am I missing? Any pointers/suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.